# Select all participants under the age of 18 using the current date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: TABLE participants]

I want to select all participants who are not 18 years old, but using the current date how do I do this.

I would not like to use the following way,

```
SELECT * FROM participants WHERE data_of_birth < '2020-01-01';
```

Does anyone know otherwise?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-current_date/

Comment: @forpas The linked "This question already has answers here" is for "how to calculate the age" not "select under the age of x". While they are similar, they are not the same.

Comment: @some Postgres offers the function age(). what else is needed? A WHERE clause.

Comment: @forpas When using *age*, the age must be calculated for each row and then compared to a constant. current_date is only updated at the start of each transaction, therefor `current_date - '18 years'::interval;` can be calculated once and that value can be compared directly to the stored value.

Comment: I new using database and PostgreSQL, THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved with an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT * FROM participants WHERE data_of_birth >  (current_date - '18 years'::interval)::date;
```